# zero inflation and endogeneity in logit or probit model

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, zero-inflation, endogeneity

What is the good model for the case of bias in the distribution of the dependent variable? The dependent variable is categorical variable and one categories are dominant (about 90%).
Although I can set dependent variable both as ordered categories (in ordered logit model) or binary (probit model), one category remains dominant.
Endogeneity must be addressed at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean that one category occurs $90\%$ of the time and the other occurs $10\%$ of the time? If so, what do you find problematic about such a situation?

Comment: Hello Dave.
I am wondering if these biased distribution in dependent variable leads to some problem when I apply non-liner regression model.

Comment: What do you mean by a “biased” distribution, that one category is represented more than the other?

Comment: I am sorry for my confusing word.
Yes, I mean the biased distributiton as just one category is super dominant to others.
I am focising on child labor as dependent variable. Since most children don't engage in labor work, it is rarely observed.

Comment: What do you find problematic about the imbalance? For instance, does it lead to you having few observations of the minority category? This situation of [tag:unbalanced-classes] I’d rather well-studied, and statistics tends not to find it problematic unless there is a lack of data about the minority category (and a lack of data is problematic in general, not just in this specific situation).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response Dave.
I am wondering the observations of minority categories (in my data, minority categories were observed in 35 out of 408 cases). I found the existence of zero inflated and hurdle models addressing these biased distribution.
However, I could not find a good way to combine the these models with the instrumental variables especially when implementing them in R.
That's why I choose ordered logistic and probit models. However, my concern is that the models may not take into account the biased distribution in dependent variable.

Comment: By continuing to call this a _bias_ you are indicating that you are not studying the responses to your question.

Comment: Hello. Dr. Frank Harrell.
Yes, I am sorry. That is not "biased distribution". It is called "unbalanced-classes".

Comment: @Sho I think it will be helpful to think about this as two distinct issues. 1) What issues are there in running an instrumental variable estimation when you have a nonlinear model and a categorical outcome? 2) What issues does the class imbalance present? $//$ Often, this second question has an answer of, “None, if you use good statistical methods,” though I have seen issues with using instruments for categorical outcomes (I’ve forgotten the details). Can you please address those two questions? (Are those even your questions?)

Comment: Even using the word _unbalanced_ is a bit harmful.  There is no reason to expect a balanced distribution.  It adds nothing to the discussion and makes some people think that there is a problem that needs fixing.